# Django REST framework: method PUT not allowed in ViewSet with def update()

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

In DRF, I have a simple ViewSet like this one:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):       

    def update(self, request):
        # do things...
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I try a PUT request, I get an error like method PUT not allowed. If I use `def put(self, request):` all things work fine. Accordingly to [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) I should use `def update():` not `def put():`, why does it happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is because the `APIView` has no handler defined for `.put()` method so the incoming request could not be mapped to a handler method on the view, thereby raising an exception.**

(Note: `viewsets.ViewSet` inherit from `ViewSetMixin` and `APIView`)

The `dispatch()` method in the `APIView` checks if a method handler is defined for the request `method`.If the `dispatch()` method finds a handler for the request method, it returns the appropriate response. Otherwise, it raises an exception [`MethodNotAllowed`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#methodnotallowed).

As per the source code of `dispatch()` method in the `APIView` class:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):       
        ...
        ...    
        try:
            self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)

            # Get the appropriate handler method
            if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
                 # here handler is fetched for the request method
                 # `http_method_not_allowed` handler is assigned if no handler was found
                handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed 

            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs) # handler is called here

        except Exception as exc:
            response = self.handle_exception(exc)

        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.response
```

Since `.put()` method handler is not defined in your view, DRF calls the fallback handler `.http_method_not_allowed`. This raises an `MethodNotAllowed` exception.

The source code for `.http_method_not_allowed()` is:

```
def http_method_not_allowed(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    If `request.method` does not correspond to a handler method,
    determine what kind of exception to raise.
    """
    raise exceptions.MethodNotAllowed(request.method) # raise an exception
```

**Why it worked when you defined `.put()` in your view?**

When you defined `def put(self, request):` in your view, DRF  could map the incoming request method to a handler method on the view. This led to appropriate response being returned without an exception being raised.

Comment: So if I wanted to use create I would just map it?

Comment: Did you define a `router` in your urls when defining  `update()` in your view?

Comment: I defined a router to register the viewSet

Comment: This method should work always. Please check if you have defined `viewsets` and `routers` properly as given in the documentation as the `router` will itself set the `put` function to point to the `update` function. So, whenever a `PUT` request comes, handler will execute the code for `.update()` action.

Comment: I registered the viewsSet in the url file. I have a router `router = routers.DefaultRouter()` and the entry for my endpoint (and for others): `router.register(r'myUrl', views.MyViewSet, 'myUrl')`

Comment: It should work by what you have specified. I would suggest putting a debugger in `dispatch()` method in DRF `views` and see what handler you are getting. If you are not getting any handler, then i would suggest checking whether the  `router` urls are being included or not.

Comment: Does the URL you are calling contain the detail 'pk' path parameter? Cause calling PUT to the root resource, eg /users/ without /users/<pk> will result in a method not allowed.

Answer (score 131):

### PUT needs `id` in URL by default

Sometimes there  is the difference between POST and PUT, because **PUT needs `id` in URL**
That's why you get the error: "*PUT is not Allowed*".

Example:

- **POST**: `/api/users/`
- **PUT**: `/api/users/1/`

Hope it'll save a lot of time for somebody

Comment: Note that if you just define the method `put` (instead of `update` via the DRF mixin) then it will work without an ID.

Comment: Sure but not all the time; imagine a 'singleton' resource, there will be no ID. A common use case for this might be if you have a `/user/me` endpoint representing the currently logged in user.

Comment: In my case this worked like a charm because I used a `viewsets.ModelViewSet` and a `serializers.ModelSerializer` related to it.

Comment: Also you can use `PATCH` method to perform partial updates of the Django model

Answer (score 13):

Had a similar "Method PUT not allowed" issue with this code, because 'id' was missing in the request:

```
class ProfileStep2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('middle_initial', 'mobile_phone', 'address', 'apt_unit_num', 'city', 'state', 'zip')

class Step2ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileStep2Serializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Profile.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.profile.id)
```

Turned out that i have missed 'id' in the serializer fields, so PUT request was NOT able to provide an id for the record. The fixed version of the serializer is below:

```
class ProfileStep2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'middle_initial', 'mobile_phone', 'address', 'apt_unit_num', 'city', 'state', 'zip')
```

Comment: u are really goooooood man ,you save me a lot of time !!

Answer (score 6):

This answer is right, [Django REST framework: method PUT not allowed in ViewSet with def update()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880227/django-rest-framework-method-put-not-allowed-in-viewset-with-def-update#answer-46615949), PUT is not allowed, because DRF expects the instance id to be in the URL. That being said, using this mixin in your ViewSet is probably the best way to fix it (from https://gist.github.com/tomchristie/a2ace4577eff2c603b1b copy pasted below)

```
class AllowPUTAsCreateMixin(object):
    """
    The following mixin class may be used in order to support PUT-as-create
    behavior for incoming requests.
    """
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object_or_none()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if instance is None:
            lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
            lookup_value = self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]
            extra_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: lookup_value}
            serializer.save(**extra_kwargs)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_object_or_none(self):
        try:
            return self.get_object()
        except Http404:
            if self.request.method == 'PUT':
                # For PUT-as-create operation, we need to ensure that we have
                # relevant permissions, as if this was a POST request.  This
                # will either raise a PermissionDenied exception, or simply
                # return None.
                self.check_permissions(clone_request(self.request, 'POST'))
            else:
                # PATCH requests where the object does not exist should still
                # return a 404 response.
                raise
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

you have registered a route like this (in urls.py)

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user-viewset')
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

and your restapi routs starts with **/api/**.

ViewSets generates follow routs.

create a user (send user object in body)
**POST**
/api/users/

get list of users
**GET**
/api/users/

get a user
**GET**
/api/users/{id}/

update a user (full object update)
**PUT**
/api/users/{id}/

partial update for a user
**PATCH**
/api/users/{id}/

delete a user
**DELETE**
/api/users/{id}/

Answer (score 0):

```
def update(self, request, pk=None):
    data_in = request.data
    print(data_in)

    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=False)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    if instance is None:
        lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
        lookup_value = self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]
        extra_kwargs = {self.lookup_field: lookup_value}
        serializer.save(**extra_kwargs)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    serializer.save()
    data_out = serializer.data
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Using Django viewsets you can easily map the method in the url e.g.

```
path('createtoken/', CreateTokenView.as_view({'post': 'create', 'put':'update'}))
```

Then in your class override the methods as you please:

```
class CreateTokenView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = yourSet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = yourSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #any method you want here
        return Response("response")

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # any method you want here
        return Response("response")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple objects that are working with `ModelViewSet` and all have different (unique) fields for lookup.

So I came up with another solution for this question by defining `put` on a parent class and a new field `lookup_body_field` that can be used to associate payload with existing object:

```
class CustomViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_body_field = 'id'

    def put(self, pk=None):
        lookup_value = self.request.data.get(self.lookup_body_field)
        if not lookup_value:
            raise ValidationError({self.lookup_body_field: "This field is mandatory"})

        obj = self.get_queryset().filter(**{self.lookup_body_field: lookup_value}).last()
        if not obj:
            return self.create(request=self.request)
        else:
            self.kwargs['pk'] = obj.pk
            return self.update(request=self.request)


class MyViewSetA(CustomViewSet)
    model = ModelA
    lookup_body_field = 'field_a'  # Unique field on ModelA

class MyViewSetB(CustomViewSet)
    model = ModelB
    lookup_body_field = 'field_b'  # Unique field on ModelA
```